# How to have inline elements within a listview in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to have a listview that has a flipswitch aligned on the right side of the list item.  Here is the code I am using:

```
<ul>
<li data-role="fieldcontain"><a href="#" onclick="openPlace();" >MyHyperlink</a><select name="slider" id="flip-a" data-role="slider"><option value="off">Off</option><option value="on" selected>On</option></select></li>
</ul>
```

This works, but will have the hyperlink above the swtch in the list item.  I tried using a table and that worked to keep them on the same line, but it ruined the jquery styling.  How can I accomplish this without messing up the styling?

Comment: can u make a fiddle for this?

Comment: i tried, but I couldn't get it to work properly.  i'll keep trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you have to embed some custom css and some additional html to this...

I have created this demo, hope this works for you,

**HTML:-**

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li>Acura
        <span class="fliper">
            <label for="flip2" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Flip switch:</label>
            <select name="flip2" id="flip2" data-role="slider">
                <option value="off">Off</option>
                <option value="on">On</option>
            </select>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>Audi</li>
    <li>BMW</li>
    <li>Cadillac</li>
    <li>Ferrari</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:-**

```
.fliper { position:absolute; right:0; top:-4px; }
```

**Working demo:-** http://jsfiddle.net/H4UzV/